# React Native - Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I got below error while trying to run my react-native app

[Image of console (same content pasted below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcaN1.png)

```
C:\My Projects\SmartBill\SmartBillApp>npx react-native run-windows --logging
 i Verbose: ON
- Locating NuGet executableINFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
 Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:90
+ ... lyContinue; Invoke-WebRequest https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandl ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 

WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

× Locating NuGet executable
error Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Object.runWindows [as func] (C:\My Projects\SmartBill\SmartBillApp\node_modules\react-native-windows\local-cli\runWindows\runWindows.js:67:61)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: It would help to see some code ;) Here is a link on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which you should read.

Comment: I have no experience in react-native. I tried to create app using the commands received from react website. Usually, when creating react or angular app, we would get a sample hello world app, right? The same is the situation here. I did no coding, but tried to run the default code which I got by installing pre-reqs and init (initialising react-native app).